# AS3 Datagrid multiple selection

Tags: actionscript-3, advanceddatagrid

I am working with Flash AS3 (not Flex) .
I have a datagrid with **"allowMultipleSelection = true";**
I want get and store the selected rows in my Data Base only when the row selection is completed using a button. (I don't want use "ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK" because a row can be selected and removed from the selection using the CTRL key)

How can I retrieve the selected rows in the datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [fl.controls.DataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html), you can use the [selectedItems](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/SelectableList.html#selectedItems) property (it's an `Array`) to get (or set) the selected items when your button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a datagrid which had checkboxes which use to get checked when a datagrid row was clicked. I wanted to allow multiple selections and also make the corresponding rows as checked or unchecked depending whether they are selected using shift key. I was able to do so by using the contains method of arraycollection and then checking the checkbox.